# Static routing not working in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, angularjs-routing

I have a small app and I have trouble with static routing:

This is my app.js config:

```
employeesApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/employees', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/employees_list.html',
                controller: 'EmployeesCtrl'
            }).
            when('/employees/add_new', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/employess_add_new.html',
                controller: 'EmployeeAddNewCtrl'
            }).
            when('/employees/:employeeId', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/employees_details.html',
                controller: 'EmployeeDetailsCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/employees'
            });
    }]);
```

The controller:

```
EmployeesControllers.controller('EmployeeAddNewCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

    }]);
```

Server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// mongodb connection and app configuration
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
});


// application
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/index.html'); // load the single view file, angular will handle other views
});
```

The main problem is that the first (/employees) and third route (/employees/:employeeId') are working ok, but the second route ('/employees/add_new') is not working, where I end up with the application constantly calling the server for the page and my browser eats whole memory and crashes.

Here is my file hierarchy:

```
Application
---app
------css
------js
--------------app.js
------partials
--------------employees_list.html
--------------employees_add_new.html
--------------employees_details.html
------lib
---server.js
```

Comment: Typo (`employess_add_new.html`)?

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/">` into your `<head></head>`. But probably it's the typo as robertklep mentioned.

Comment: Do you have `app.use(app.router);`?

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, it was a stupid typo. I guess my tired eyes couldn't see it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a typo at

```
       `when('/employees/add_new', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/employess_add_new.html',
            controller: 'EmployeeAddNewCtrl'
        }).`
```

should be `employees`